# Is it valid to static_cast 'weak_ptr<SomeThing>*' to 'void*' then back to 'weak_ptr<void>*' , or do I need to use static_pointer_cast?

Tags: c++, lua, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I'm embedding Lua scripting in my program, and part of that is allowing Lua to manage the lifetime of some shared and weak pointers. I do that by constructing a pointer in some Lua managed memory (called 'userdata'). At a later time when Lua is about to garbage collect that memory, it calls back to my code with a `void*` to the memory. At that point, I can cast the `void*` back to a `weak_ptr` and call the `reset()` method before the memory gets freed.

My question is, can I get away with using the same garbage collection callback (`__gc` metamethod in lua-speak) for every type of `weak_ptr`? This would necessitate `static_cast`'ing directly from `void*` to `weak_ptr<void>*`, even though I constructed a `weak_ptr<something>` at that memory location. Is that valid?

Here's the relavent snips of code:

```
void* p = lua_newuserdatauv(L,sizeof(std::weak_ptr<asio::io_service::strand>),0);
new(p) std::weak_ptr<asio::io_service::strand>(pSyncStrand);
luaL_getmetatable(L, "std_weak_ptr");
lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
```

And here is the metatable `__gc` method that is called with the `void*` (`p` above):

```
luaL_newmetatable(L,"std_weak_ptr");
lua_pushcfunction(L, [](lua_State* const L) -> int
    {
        auto weak_ptr = static_cast<std::weak_ptr<void>*>(lua_touserdata(L,1));
        weak_ptr->reset();
        return 0;
    });
lua_setfield(L,-2,"__gc");
```

Or will I need a separate metatable for every variant of `weak_ptr`? My tests seem to indicate the above code works, but I want to make sure it's valid and not UB or implementation dependent.

**EDIT: Here's my updated code based on Remy Lebeau's answer**

The __gc routine is updated to destroy, not just reset, the weak_ptr

```
luaL_newmetatable(L,"std_weak_ptr_void");
lua_pushcfunction(L, [](lua_State* const L) -> int
    {
        auto weak_ptr = static_cast<std::weak_ptr<void>*>(lua_touserdata(L,1));
        std::destroy_at(weak_ptr);
        return 0;
    });
lua_setfield(L,-2,"__gc");
```

And here is how I store the pointer now

```
void* p = lua_newuserdatauv(L,sizeof(std::weak_ptr<void>),0);
new(p) std::weak_ptr<void>(pSyncStrand);
luaL_getmetatable(L, "std_weak_ptr_void");
lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
```

And as an addition, this is how I use it in the meantime

```
auto ppSync = static_cast<std::weak_ptr<void>*>(lua_touserdata(L, lua_upvalueindex(1)));
auto pSync = std::static_pointer_cast<asio::io_service::strand>(ppSync->lock());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is UB to convert a given pointer to a `void*` and then convert the `void*` to a different pointer type.

`weak_ptr<something>` and `weak_ptr<void>` are separate and unrelated types. The `void*` must be converted back to the original pointer type it was created from.

So, convert the `weak_ptr<something>` to `weak_ptr<void>` first, then convert that to `void*`, then you can convert the `void*` back to `weak_ptr<void>`.

---

On a separate note: since you are using `placement-new` to create the `weak_ptr` in a memory block allocated by Lua, make sure you destruct the `weak_ptr` before Lua frees the allocated memory. Which means you have to know the original `weak_ptr` type that you created so you can call its destructor correctly. Calling `reset()` on a `weak_ptr` releases the reference that the `weak_ptr` holds to another object. It does not destroy the `weak_ptr` itself.

Comment: Cool. I suspected as much. So if I use a static_pointer_cast to convert the weak_pointer<something> to weak_ptr<void> and store that in the lua managed memory, then I can still have my cake and eat it too. Ie, I can static_cast from void* back to weak_ptr<void>*, then static_pointer_cast back to weak_ptr<something> where I need to, but in the garbage collector routine, I only need to cast back to weak_ptr<void>, call reset() and call destructor?

Comment: I've accepted your answer and added updated code in the question based on your answer. It would be great if you can check I understood correctly. Thanks.

Comment: @NeilStephens you are using `destroy_at()` incorrectly (drop the `&`). And there is no need to `reset()` a `weak_ptr` that you are about to destroy since its destructor will handle that for you.